# How to compile a dlib example using eclipse in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse-cdt, dlib

I downloaded dlib and I want to compile one of the files in the examples directory using eclipse-cdt  in windows. Here is what I did for now :

- Download dlib to C:\dlib-18.18
- Create a new project in eclipse
- Create a folder src in this project
- Put a file from examples directory inside src (for example face_dection_ex.cpp)
- Put dlib/all/source.ccp inside src
- Add C:\dlib-18.18\dlib to my include paths (GCC C++ Compiler)
- Add DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT to my preprocessor (GCC C++ compiler)
- Add the following libraries in MinGW Linker : comctl32, user32, winmm, imm32,gdi32, ws2_32

When I try to build my project, I get the following error :

..\src\source.cpp:7:41: fatal error: ../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp: No such file or directory
 #include "../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp"
                                         ^
compilation terminated

Can you pkease tell me what I am missing ?

Comment: I changed all the includes in source.cpp file like this : from ../base64/.... to dlib/base64 . Now I am getting the folliwing error : C:\dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp:17:24: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
 #   include <jpeglib.h>

Comment: Don't move or modify any files in the dlib folder.

Comment: Should I include source.cpp in my include paths (-I option) ? or shoud I copy paste it in my project folder (where ?) ?

Comment: No. Don't do either of those things. Tell eclipse to compile source.cpp. Don't move the file though. If you don't know how to add files to eclipse for compiling then use cmake to generate the eclipse project.

Comment: I tried to generate an eclipse project like this : cd example; cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" . ; but importing the examples directory in eclipse generates an error. Is this the correct way to do this ? If not can you show me how ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how to achieve this thanks to Davis' suggestions.

Requirements :

- Install cmake : https://cmake.org/
- Install MinGW : http://www.mingw.org/

Steps :

- cd examples
- cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ .
- This last command will generate the required files for an eclipse project
- Now Open eclipse and new->import->general->import existing projects into workspace , then choose examples directory. This will import the project generated by cmake to your workspace.
- Enjoy your developements with dlib !!

Note :

These steps can also work if you create a new project that uses dlib. All you have to do is copy the CMakeLists file to your directory and adapt it to your project.