# Errors while installing/using dlib for use with Eclipse CDT, MinGW and OpenCV

Tags: windows, opencv, mingw, eclipse-cdt, dlib

I use Eclipse Neon CDT with MinGW. I have CMake at my disposal.

I want to work with dlib and OpenCV in Eclipse CDT, and be able to compile my project just by clicking on the 'Build' button, without having to leave Eclipse, if possible.

I am working on a project that requires both OpenCV and dlib. I've successfully installed OpenCV and tested it with some programs to make sure it works. However, I'm having problems using dlib.

I used CMake gui to Configure/Generate,`mingw32-make` and `mingw32-make install` commands to set up my dlib library. This library was at C:/Program Files/Project and contained three folders `include`, `lib` and `share`

I started a new Project in Eclipse CDT and set my include paths to `C:/Program Files/Project/include` and added the following libraries (all .dll files)-
gdi32, comctl32, user32, winmm, ws2_32, imm32

When I went ahead and copy/pasted the code from the example file, [face-landmark-detection-ex.cpp](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html) and tried to build it, the Build Console displayed these [errors](https://gist.github.com/kartikeygupta/7dbedb2096759a0b46fd4e7175255870).

These are the statements that caused the errors - 
`image_window win, win_faces;` (line 34),
`win.clear();` (line 52) and
`win.add_overlay(render_face_detections(shapes));` (line 54)

I don't know if it's relevant, but when I tried the method mentioned, in the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937454/how-to-compile-a-dlib-example-using-eclipse-in-windows), the build was successful and the executable worked, but I couldn't include OpenCV headers and libs this way, so I had to look for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the instructions on dlib's [how to compile page](http://dlib.net/compile.html)?

> ### Compiling C++ Examples Without CMake
>
> In most cases, to use this library all you have to do is extract it
>   somewhere, make sure the folder containing the dlib folder is in your
>   include path, and finally add dlib/all/source.cpp to your project.

It doesn't sound like you added dlib/all/source.cpp to your project.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for asking what might be stupid question, but how do I add 'source.cpp' to my project. I know that in your previous answer you advised against moving/copying the file to the working directory, so I imported it to my project. But then it would give a `fatal error : file not found`. I also tried to build without any of the .dll files, and then it gives a `fatal error : base64_kernel_1.cpp: No such file or directory`.

Comment: How do you add any cpp files to your project?  Don't you have code?

Comment: So I just copy paste the code in the source file to my working file?

Comment: No. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: I have added source.cpp to the working directory as you instructed and the build gives a `..\source.cpp:11:41: fatal error: ../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp: No such file or directory
 #include "../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp"` error.`

Comment: Don't move the source.cpp file.  Just tell your compiler to compile it into your program.  Every C++ IDE has some menu that says something like "add this file" or something similar.  If you can't figure out how to compile files on your computer without moving them around in the filesystem then you need to take a step back from this and learn to use your tools or find a different IDE that is less confusing to you.

Comment: Yes. I get what you are saying, and this time I'm confident that I have added source.cpp to the project.

Comment: new [errors](https://gist.github.com/kartikeygupta/a789d7288c2efc4bc69c27a79ea8c647)